# get hard disk drive name in which windows OS installed using NSIS

Tags: nsis, hard-drive

I need to get hard disk drive letter like C: or D: or any in which the OS is installed on any windows.

Kindly help me get out of this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Section
StrCpy $0 $sysdir 3
DetailPrint $0
SectionEnd
```

`$SYSDIR` is the Windows system directory (usually `C:\Windows\System` or `C:\WinNT\System32`, but that's detected at runtime).

`StrCpy` has the syntax `StrCpy user_var(destination) str(source) [maxlen] [start_offset]` where `maxlen` and `start_offset` are optional.

So the code above, copies the first three letters from `$SYSDIR` into the `$0` variable.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a little bit of an explanation for the OP and for future readers.